# match a pattern in text and read it to different variables

Tags: python-3.x, regex, parsing

I have the following pattern: `<num1>-<num2> <char a-z>: <string>`. For example, `1-3 z: zztop`

I'd like to parse them to `n1=1, n2=3, c='z', s='zztop'`

Of course I can do this easily with splitting but is there a more compact way to do that in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `re.finditer` with a regex having named capture groups:

```py
inp = "1-3 z: zztop"
r = re.compile('(?P<n1>[0-9]+)-(?P<n2>[0-9]+) (?P<c>\w+):\s*(?P<s>\w+)')
output = [m.groupdict() for m in r.finditer(inp)]
print(output)  # [{'n1': '1', 'n2': '3', 'c': 'z', 's': 'zztop'}]
```